# How to disable slide effect in firefox 12.0

Tags: firefox

I just update firefox and they use a smooth slide effect(When the mouse wheel scrolls), but it is a real pain for me, because I normally view lost-of-images sites. Could anyone help to disable this? Must I use older versions?

Comment: Definitely belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > Advanced > General > Browsing` and uncheck `Use Smooth Scrolling`.